Why is it that $f(x)>g(x)$ does not imply $f'(x)>g'(x)$ but it implies that $\int f(x) > \int g(x)$?
This is a question, I was solving 
Background:
Let $$f(x)=\int^x_0\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt-2x+1$$
Then $$f'(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}-2=\frac{x^2-2x^4-2}{1+x^4}$$
Which is always negative$\implies$function a strictly decreasing one$\implies$ at most one root
$f(0)=1>0$;
$f(1)=\int^1_0\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt-2+1<0$
Since $$(t^2-1)^2\ge 0$$
$$\implies \frac{t^2}{1+t^4}<1$$
$$\implies \int^1_0\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt<\left(\int^1_0 dt=1\right)$$
Therefore $f(1)<0$
So there is a root.
Questions:
In this question it is stated that there is no general condition for which  $$f(x)>g(x)\implies f'(x)>g'(x)$$ However in the solution, a step essentially uses:
$$f(x)>g(x)\implies \int f(x)>\int g(x) $$
But integration is the inverse of differentiation. So how come one holds while the other does not? Does the property hold for constant=0 in $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that is if there is no constant term is absent does $f(x)>g(x) \implies f'(x)>g'(x)$?

Why should one hold if the other does?  A function having higher $y$-coordinates than another doesn't have to also be steeper.

The intuïtion comes down to the derivative measures slope (local) the integral has to do with the surface under the curve which is more global I guess

For a severe example, $f(x) = 2$ is always above $g(x)=\arctan(x)$, yet $f'=0$.

The fact that integration is [nearly] the inverse of differentiation means that the relationship between your two implications is [nearly] the same as logical converses.  That is, we might know $P \to Q$ is true, but this tells us nothing about whether $Q \to P$ is true or not.

Compare $\sin x^{-1}$ and the constant $2$ on $(0, 1)$.

A square is a rectangle but a rectangle isn't necessarily a square. Just because a statement is true in one direction doesn't mean it has to be true in the other direction.

@Randall I understand the examples but  $$f(x)>g(x)\implies \int f(x)>\int g(x)$$ Then if the integral of the functions are $$F(x) \text{ and } G(x)$$ doesn't it reduce to $$F(x)>G(x)\implies F'(x)>G'(x)$$

@Aruralreader

Should I edit the original question to include what I asked in this comment?

You have the order reversed.  If $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are the integrals, then it becomes $$F'(x) > G'(x) \implies F(x) > G(x)$$ which is true, at least under the assumption $F(a) = G(a)$ and $x > a$.  (again, like I said in my previous comment and like AmaanM said too, your statements are essentially converses, so there's no reason they should be equivalent)

@Aurelius you’ve got it backwards.  That matters.

@BrianMoehring Oh My ! That's it. So a function with greater steepness will have greater value and  a car with greater velocity will always have greater displacement

Your question can be reformulatef as follows. Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x).$ Then you are interested whether $h(x)>0$ implies $h'(x)>0.$ Clearly it does not hold as there are positive and strictly decreasing functions. For instance $h(x)=e^{-x}>0,$ $h'(x)=-e^{-x}<0.$

But if   $$f(x)>g(x)\implies \int f(x)>\int g(x)$$ Let the integral of the functions are $$F(x) \text{ and } G(x)$$ doesn't it reduce to $$F(x)>G(x)\implies F'(x)>G'(x)$$

@Aurelius $ a\implies b$ doesn't mean that $b \implies a$. All humans are mortal, but not all mortals are human. In your case it is true that $F' > G' \implies F>G$, but  there not need be a reverse implication.
